# What was that horror movie where a priest is chopping a chocolate bar?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

There was this old horror film, maybe around the 90s or late 80s, where in one scene, a priest or someone in a church was in a table chopping a piece of a Snickers bar, or chocolate.

In the blurred background was a crucifix with a life-sized statue of Jesus hanging from it.

As the priest was chopping, the blurred figure of Jesus starts to move, removing the nails from his hands and feet, walked to the priest and sat beside him, while the priest was obviously afraid and speechless.

I saw this while I was a kid, but didn't watch further because it scared the heck out of me.

- This should be an English film.
- The priest was wearing a dark robe of some sort
- He was using a small knife to cut the chocolate bar on the table while he was sitting.
- From what I can recall, the subject of the film was a metal or golden circular seal breaking somewhere.
- This should be around the 90s, I saw it on a rented tape only.

Comment: Hi! I might know this, but do you happen to remember the country\language?

Comment: Hi, I know it is an English movie because back then, I know there were no subtitles yet and I could understand it. I am asian but we grew up watching english movies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the horror film [Catacombs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106636/combined) (AKA Curse IV: The Ultimate Sacrifice) from 1988. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catacombs_(1988_film)):

> In the 17th century, an order of monks in Italy capture and entomb a demon that has possessed a member of their group. 400 years later, school teacher Elizabeth Magrino (Laura Schaefer) visits the monastery in order to do some research. What she and the current monks do not realize is that the evil hiding within the catacombs has unwittingly been released.

You can see the scene you were looking for below with a priest cutting up a candy bar with a knife *[[Mr Pitt wouldv'e been proud ;)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11neMoelz8g#t=1m58s)]* in church as Jesus slowly comes down from the cross behind him and eventually stabs him: